# Efficient way to recode multiple date values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a quite large monthly database where the dates are recorded in a poorly way.

For instance, for January 2000, the value is "200001". So I have values ranging from "200001" to "200012". To make matters worse, each month is recorded in a different .csv file.

First, I loaded all .csv files together, creating a list I called "tbl". So tbl[[1]] returns the values for the month of January, for example. What I need is to encounter an efficient way to revalue "20000i" to "2000-01-0i", where i goes from 1 to 12, and then converting those values to date format.

What I've tried is:

```
for (i in length(tbl)) {
  if (i < 10) {
    tbl[[i]]$DATA %>% as.character() %>% revalue(c(paste0("20000",i) = paste0("2000-01-0",i))) %>%  as.Date() -> tbl[[i]]$DATA
  } else {
    tbl[[i]]$DATA %>% as.character() %>% revalue(c(paste0("2000",i) = paste0("2000-01-",i))) %>%  as.Date() -> tbl[[i]]$DATA
  }
}
```

This approach is not working and return the following error: 
`Error: unexpected '=' in "    tbl[[i]]$DATA %>% as.character() %>% revalue(c(paste0("2000",i) ="`

Does anybody have a better idea?

EDIT: an example of my data

```
list(c("200001", "200001", "200001", "200001", "200001", "200001","200001", "200001", "200001", "200001", "200001", "200001"), 
c("200002", "200002", "200002", "200002", "200002", "200002", 
"200002", "200002", "200002", "200002", "200002", "200002"
), c("200003", "200003", "200003", "200003", "200003", "200003", 
"200003", "200003", "200003", "200003", "200003", "200003"
), c("200004", "200004", "200004", "200004", "200004", "200004", 
"200004", "200004", "200004", "200004", "200004", "200004"
), c("200005", "200005", "200005", "200005", "200005", "200005", 
"200005", "200005", "200005", "200005", "200005", "200005"
), c("200006", "200006", "200006", "200006", "200006", "200006", 
"200006", "200006", "200006", "200006", "200006", "200006"
), c("200007", "200007", "200007", "200007", "200007", "200007", 
"200007", "200007", "200007", "200007", "200007", "200007"
), c("200008", "200008", "200008", "200008", "200008", "200008", 
"200008", "200008", "200008", "200008", "200008", "200008"
), c("200009", "200009", "200009", "200009", "200009", "200009", 
"200009", "200009", "200009", "200009", "200009", "200009"
), c("200010", "200010", "200010", "200010", "200010", "200010", 
"200010", "200010", "200010", "200010", "200010", "200010"
), c("200011", "200011", "200011", "200011", "200011", "200011", 
"200011", "200011", "200011", "200011", "200011", "200011"
), c("200012", "200012", "200012", "200012", "200012", "200012", 
"200012", "200012", "200012", "200012", "200012", "200012"
))
```

Comment: Just make them dates? Please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Thank you, @Dave2e, it was exactly what I was looking for! I would appreciate if you could make it a proper answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert your input into a date object you will need to add a day onto the yearmonth and then use the proper format:

```
for (i in 1:length(tbl)) {
   tbl[[i]]$DATA <- as.Date(paste(tbl[[i]]$DATA, 01), "%Y%m %d")
}
```

This will make every input the first day or the month.  For just a dozen itens, a `for` loop is a quick enough.

Comment: You mean `1:length(tbl)` or `seq_along(tbl)` :)